# Fixing the edge of this knife

Tags: knife-sharpening

I have an old knife that I want to put a straight, sharp edge on.

[image]

Due to bad sharpening habits and use the edge has gotten nicked up and uneven.

I bought a Sharpal 181 duel grit diamond sharpener, and I wanted to get some input on the best way to do the job.

Should I go at the edge with the coarse side until the nicks are gone, then switch to fine?
Is there a better way?

Comment: @noah Maybe. It's a bit different, mostly because it's the nicks that I'm really wondering about. Also the Sharpal tool isn't a whetstone. But there are a few tips in there that might be useful.

Comment: I think you'll need to take the edge back to get rid of the nicks then sharpen, but I'm no expert

Comment: @bob1 That's kind of what I'm wondering, specifically the best way to do that.
Like, should I just take it to a bench grinder and go flat along the edge until the nicks are gone, then sharpen at an angle again, or just keep sharpening at an angle until I wear enough material away for the nicks to be gone? I've been periodically been running it along the course side as I've been sitting here, and it seems like some of the smaller nicks are gone, and only the two slightly bigger ones are left, so maybe this way is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been periodically running the coarse side across the blade, and eventually ground out the nicks.
I'm still hoping that someone who actually knows what they are doing let's me know a better way.
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So, having taken back the blade to remove the nicks, is the time to continue with the fine grinding. I My father would keep his razor sharp with a *leather* strop.

Comment: @WeatherVane I do need to do a bit more research on that. The tool has a leather sheath that can be used for stropping, but I should work on learning the right way to do that, and also I don't know if I need anything other than the leather.